# Flask Apache Integration

Tags: python, apache, python-2.7, flask, wsgi

I've been struggling for a few days to get my Flask App served out from Apache - it's driving me crazy. If you could point me in the right direction; that'd be great. Any idea why this isn't working? Thanks!

My directory structure looks like this:

```
apps
├── sandbox
│   ├── decorators
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   └── style.css
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   └── Elements
│   │   │       └── index.html
│   │   └── views.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── sandbox.wsgi
```

I'm getting the Apache error log as follows:

```
[Wed Dec 31 16:20:52 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Dec 31 16:20:56 2014] [error] [client 81.174.155.229] mod_wsgi (pid=8048): Target WSGI script '/apps/sandbox.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Dec 31 16:20:56 2014] [error] [client 81.174.155.229] mod_wsgi (pid=8048): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/apps/sandbox.wsgi'.
[Wed Dec 31 16:20:56 2014] [error] [client 81.174.155.229] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Dec 31 16:20:56 2014] [error] [client 81.174.155.229]   File "/apps/sandbox.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
[Wed Dec 31 16:20:56 2014] [error] [client 81.174.155.229]     from sandbox import app as application
[Wed Dec 31 16:20:56 2014] [error] [client 81.174.155.229] ImportError: No module named sandbox
```

My **sandbox.wsgi** file looks like this:

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/apps/sandbox/")
from sandbox import app as application
application.secret_key = 'secrethash'`
```

My uppermost **init**.py contains:

```
from flask import Flask
from decorators.views import profile
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(profile)
```

Finally, my Apache virtualhost config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.sandbox
    ServerAdmin admin@local.sandbox
    WSGIScriptAlias / /apps/sandbox.wsgi
    <Directory /apps/sandbox/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sys.path.insert(0,"/apps/")` if you want to import sandbox?

Comment: You're completely right. It's always the small things! Thanks @mensi